# Overcoming unclosed tags in xsl

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, tags

I'm working on a drop down menu that pulls data from a Sharepoint list and is styled with xsl. The html structure is a simple unordered list

```
<ul><li>parent page</li><ul><li>sub page 1</li><li>sub page2</li></ul></ul>
```

The xsl tests if an item in the list is a parent page or a sub page and what the sub page number is. Parent pages have a number so the desired sub pages can be attached to the correct parent page.

The basic xsl for each item is this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Data/Row">
    <xsl:if test="./@Page_x0020_type = 0">
        <li >
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of
                     select="./@Page_x002f_link_x0020_url"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="./@Title0"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:if>
```

I want the xsl to equate to this:
If it's a sub page, precede the item with a ul tag and if it's the last sub page under a parent, add a closing ul tag.

How do I get around the fact that xsl won't let me add an unclosed ul tag because it (rightly) doesn't know if the tag is going to get closed?

XML

```
    <Field Type="Text" 
           DisplayName="Page/link url" 
           Required="FALSE" 
           MaxLength="255" 
           Name="Page_x002f_link_x0020_url"/>
    <Field ReadOnly="TRUE" 
           Type="Computed" 
           Name="LinkTitle" 
           DisplayName="Page number"/>
    <Field Type="Text" 
           DisplayName="Title" 
           Required="FALSE" 
           MaxLength="255" 
           Name="Title0"/>  
    <Field Type="Choice" 
           DisplayName="Page type" 
           Required="FALSE" 
           Format="RadioButtons" 
           FillInChoice="FALSE" 
           Name="Page_x0020_type">    
           <CHOICES>  
               <CHOICE>0</CHOICE>  
               <CHOICE>1</CHOICE>  
           </CHOICES>  
           <DefaultFormula>=0</DefaultFormula>  
           <DefaultFormulaValue/>  
    </Field>
    <Field Type="Text" 
           DisplayName="Sub page number" 
           Required="FALSE" 
           MaxLength="2" 
           Name="Sub_x0020_page_x0020_number"/>
    <Field Type="Text" 
           DisplayName="Parent page number" 
           Required="FALSE" 
           MaxLength="1" 
           Name="Parent_x0020_page_x0020_number">
           <Default>0</Default>
    </Field>
</Schema>
<Data ItemCount="1">
    <Row Page_x002f_link_x0020_url="" 
         LinkTitle="" 
         Title0="" 
         Page_x0020_type="" 
         Sub_x0020_page_x0020_number="" 
         Parent_x0020_page_x0020_number="" 
         ul="" 
         _x003c_li_x003e__x003c_a_x003e_="" 
         _x003c__x002f_a_x003e__x003c__x0="" 
         _x003c_ul_x003e__x003c_li_x003e_="" 
         _x003c__x002f_a_x003e__x003c__x00="" 
         _x003c__x002f_a_x003e__x003c__x01=""/>
```

---

#### UPDATE:

Page types:

- Parent `<li>parent1</li>`
- Sub page 1 - needs to start with a `<ul>...<li>sub page 1</li>`
- Middle sub pages-(numbered to set sort order-html same as parent page) `<li>sub page #</li>`
- Last sub page in group - needs to end with a `</ul>`

Comment: You also need to formulate your algorithm differently. Think in terms of how the elements are nested, not in terms of which open or close tag precedes which text.

Comment: @matt: Your problem is that you are not thinking in terms of declarative paradigm. But you'll hardly get an answer without an input source showing how the parent-child relationship is expressed.

Comment: @John Can you elaborate? I could add "first sub page" and "last sub page" to the xml, but wouldn't I still have to introduce an unclosed tag somewhere? I'm easily confused by xsl.

Comment: @matt Your XML sample seems rather incomplete. Could you just include the part between the <Data></Data> tags with more than one row? Also, the row element doesn't actually have any data present in your example?

Comment: @matt: given the XML (quite unformed but recoverable) that you provided, you must also specify the exact result you want to be produced from it. Please, do.

Comment: @matt: Indentation is a nice way to treat your human friends...

Comment: @matt, see update to my answer below. I added a working example based on a simple XML representation of your data structure.

Answer (score 4):

> I want the xsl to equate to this: If it's a sub page, precede the item with a ul tag and if it's the last sub page under a parent, add a closing ul tag.

You're thinking the wrong way. XSLT doesn't write tags, it writes a tree of nodes. You can't write half a node to the result tree.

In XSLT 2.0 you can probably do what you want using xsl:for-each-group with the group-starting-with attribute - I can't be specific, because you haven't specified the problem clearly enough, but it's probably something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="li[....]">
    <ul>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0 then it will be more difficult: I would use a technique called "sibling recursion" in which you apply-templates to the first child, which in turn applies templates to the next sibling, and so on. The template rule for the parent does this:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The template rule for a sibling that is to be the first in a group does this:

```
<xsl:template match="parent/*[ (: where this is the first in a group :) ]">
  <group>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
  </group>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[(* start of next group *)][1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and the template rule for other siblings does:

```
<xsl:template match="parent/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The details can be tricky even for experienced XSLT developers.

Comment: @Michael-for an inexperienced xslt developer, the details are more than "tricky"! I'll have to study your suggestion a bit so I understand it. I am stuck with xslt 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing something. As XSL is an XML document that can be used to transform another XML (XHTML, SOAP, etc) document into another format, which is generally XML of some sort. If you feed a data document (string, etc) into a XSL, it transform according to the pattern you have set, which must be valid XML.

Now, why is this a problem in your instance. Are you only building part of the structure and then adding it to another part until you have the whole? If so, I would pull all of the bits into one piece of data (file, string, etc) and run the transformation on it. Or, leave placeholders in the highest level, properly end tagged, and add the child bits in that way.

Looking at your question, I see you want one valid  and one invalid , which leads me to believe you are trying to piecemeal a solution. Unfortunately, I know of no way to tell XSL "hey this is invalid XML, but don't sweat it".

Comment: XSL can also output HTML or even plain text.

Comment: Years ago, we used to use XSLT to transform XML into winword reports by outputting RTF from the XSLT transform :-)