# Grouping items in a Sharepoint list with xsl 1.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is a follow up question to the thread at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823938/overcoming-unclosed-tags-in-xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823938/)

This is for a drop down menu based on a Sharepoint list. Menu items can be added at random to the list and the page type/page grouping field determines their position in the menu.

I wasn't able to get the solution proposed in the original question that involved "recursive siblings" to work so came up with a workaround that works but I'm sure could use some streamlining.

What I'm doing now is specifying the page group to ensure the sub pages go with the right parent page. the downside is I have to specify every page group. The question is how do I get xsl to recognize a parent page (type 1) and its sub pages (type 2) programmatically without specifying what they are individually? The "linktitle" element is the page group number so it has to be repeated for each page.

I guess I'm looking for something that groups every item with the same page group number regardless of what that is. And I only have access to xsl 1.0.

XML

```
<Root>

<Schema>
<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Page url" Required="FALSE" MaxLength="255"   Name="Page_x0020_url"/>
<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Page title" Required="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Name="Page_x0020_title"/>
<Field ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Page group number"/>
<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Page number" Required="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Name="Page_x0020_number"/>

<Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="Page type" Required="FALSE" Format="RadioButtons" FillInChoice="FALSE" Name="Page_x0020_type">
<Default>2</Default>

<CHOICES>
<CHOICE>1</CHOICE>
<CHOICE>2</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
</Field>
</Schema>

<Data ItemCount="1">
<Row Page_x0020_url="" Page_x0020_title="" LinkTitle="" Page_x0020_number="" Page_x0020_type=""/>
</Data>
</Root>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" /> 
  <xsl:template match="/">

<!--  Render contents -->
<ul id ="navbar" class="">
<li>
 <xsl:for-each select="//Data/Row">
  <xsl:if test="./@LinkTitle = 1">
   <xsl:if test="./@Page_x0020_type = 1">
<a href="{./@Page_x0020_url}">         
<xsl:value-of select = "./@Page_x0020_title" />
</a>
     </xsl:if></xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="//Data/Row">
 <xsl:sort select="./@Page_x0020_number" data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:if test="./@LinkTitle = 1">
   <xsl:if test="./@Page_x0020_type = 2">
<li>
<a href="{@Page_x0020_url}"> 
     <xsl:value-of select = "@Page_x0020_title" />
</a></li>
 </xsl:if></xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</li>
<!---REPEAT ABOVE FOR EACH PAGE GROUP-->
</ul>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>G
```

Comment: You forgot to explain almost everything -- why should people even try to guess? Not to speak that the XML and code are unreadable due to lack of any indentation. Not to speak that no wanted output is presented and no explanation is given what are the desired properties of the transformation. Fail!

Comment: @Dimitre-Sorry, the explanation was in the question I linked to but I expanded on what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Your transform applied on the input above produces an empty list. You are speaking about page type and page groups assuming that someone could understand what you mean. I read this question 4 times and still I'm not getting what you are asking for.

Comment: Every item in the Sharepoint list is assigned a page group id ("linktitle") and a page type ("Page_x0020_type"). This groups the list items together and identifies them as either parent pages or sub pages and works fine. The output is a simple css driven drop down menu. What I'm trying to do is eliminate the need to specify the page group numbers and automatically group pages with the same group id. And then control the order by sorting on the group id.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the following "hack".  Note the unclosed div tag below.

```
 <xsl:if test="@ID mod 2 = 0" > <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<div>]]></xsl:text></xsl:if>
```

Comment: Sorry the title was a bit misleading because it was s follow up to an earlier question and the issue has changed a bit so I just changed the title. Once again, the transformation works fine, I'm just trying to streamline it. Can you elaborate on how your suggestion would do that?

Comment: It wouldn't help your initial question.  My snippet shows how to have an un-enclosed tag within an if statement in xsl.